# executing commands in shell and turnoff the default displays of commands in console

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

This is my script

```
cd /opt/product/vinoth
-- some operations --
cd -
```

While executing this command `cd -` the old path get displayed in the console.

is there is any way to block this from displaying in console.

The same can be avoided in make files by using @ infront of the command.

By surfing i understood that this can be achieved using `cmd=$(cd -)`

The command was not executing and path was not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OLDPWD` instead:

```
/ $ cd /tmp
/tmp $ echo $OLDPWD
/
/tmp $ cd "$OLDPWD"
/ $
```

From `man bash`:

```
   OLDPWD The previous working directory as set by the cd command.
...
cd 
   An argument of - is converted to $OLDPWD before the directory 
   change is attempted.
```

`$(cd -)` is run in a subshell, so it cannot affect the current shell.

You can also do:

```
cd - >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179540/33055) answer, a short variant to not display the directory when cd to the previous working directory is using the tilde expansion `~-`:

```
cd ~-
```