# cd to previous directory without echo of directory name

Tags: bash, cd-command

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81229/99599) gave me `cd -` as shorthand to change to my previous directory in Bash. It does have a major problem: it prints the directory it changes to, wasting my screen space, as that directory is then repeated in the prompt on the next line.

I know I can do `cd $OLDPWD`, also mentioned in that answer, and `cd - >/dev/null` but that is much more typing.

In the `bash` man page it says:

> ... or if - is the first argument, and the directory change is successful, the absolute path name of the  new  working  directory  is written to the standard output.

How can I make `-` not to be the first argument? By using any of the `cd` optional arguments? Any other way to suppress the echo or minimise typing *without* the need for defining functions/aliases on every machine I work with?

Comment: Pretty much the same question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171260)...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cd` only takes the first argument into account, ignoring all others. None of the options influence the echo of the previous pathname (maybe the documented `-@` does have that effect, but that is an invalid option on my system).

If you don't want to use an alias/function, which could give you even less characters to type than `cd -`, or redirect to `/dev/null`, my suggestion is to start using the special tilde expansion in `bash`:

```
cd ~-
```

From `bash` man page:

> If the tilde-prefix is a `~-', the value of the  shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted.

This seems to be yet another area in `bash` where some special meaning was created. Tilde expansion normally works on the $DIRSTACK, manipulated/investigated by `pushd`, `popd`, and `dirs`, it can be used in other commands as well (`cp ~-/somefile .`) and if you have used `pushd` you can use `~N` (where N is a number of levels pushed back) to get to these directories (for `cd` or other commands).

---

BTW if you have accounts on multiple machines and assuming you use ssh to login to them from one place, you should consider adding to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_common ]; then
    . ~/.bash_common
fi
```

and then have script on your work machine that uses `scp` to "push" `bash_common` to each of those machines. That way you can add and share common functionality over multiple machines with minimal overhead.